# Delete rows from grid view programmatic

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have gridview, it's datasource is `list<string>` and I added one checkbox column to select rows that I want to delete then I press delete.

```
attachdatagrid.DataSource = ConceptProperties.conceptsattachmentsfilename[mouseOverIndex].Select(x => new { FileName = x }).ToList();
```

the problem is my

> gridview EditMode

properties is  EditOnKeystroke, and when I wrote

```
if ((bool)dr.Cells[0].Value != false)
                        {
                            found = true;
                            ConceptProperties.conceptsattachments[mouseeditIndex].RemoveAt(dr.Index);
                            ConceptProperties.conceptsattachmentsfilename[mouseeditIndex].RemoveAt(dr.Index);
                            attachdatagrid.Rows.RemoveAt(dr.Index);
                        }
```

I got exception :

> Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is
>   data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and
>   allows deletion.

how can I delete the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better bind your grid to a binding source and do all manipulations on it(the binding source) rather than the list itself.
You can do that by dropping a binding source component to your form, then setting its data source to the list and the grid's data source to the binding source.

IList doesn't support change notifications. IBindingList(which binding source implements) does.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it *should be* enough to remove required data from the list and as its binded to the grid, the change in the list will be automatically propagated on UI control.

In other words: do not call `attachdatagrid.Rows.RemoveAt(dr.Index)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @salamonti: did you try to reassign the changed list? I saw that you use ToList(), this method creates a COPY of the original one, so the changes you made do not affect the list which is actually bound to the control. Reassign again to DataGrid, like in first line of the code provided.

Comment: but if I have multi checked rows it will delete only the first row because it will initialize the grid datasource again so they will be unchecked

Comment: Delete all elements you need from the list, and `after` re-bind it to the control.